# How do I create simple REST APIs in Django with a MongoEngine backend?

Tags: django, api, rest, mongoengine, tastypie

Tastypie looked promising, now not so much:

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/non_orm_data_sources.html

Should I use SimpleAPI or is there a better solution?

Comment: Finally I stopped using mongoengine...

Comment: What about that doc page says that Tastypie won't work with Mongo?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm i'm using this https://github.com/mitar/django-tastypie-mongoengine

Answer (score 0):

I once used [django-piston](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-piston/0.2.1). You should try it out, it's easy to create a rest api and it's integrated with django.

I've read it can be done with MongoEngine, but never tryed.

Answer (score 0):

The finally solution was to use django-tastypie + django-tastypie-mongoengine:

https://github.com/mitar/django-tastypie-mongoengine

Once you have that installed, in your app add a resource.py with code like this:

```
from models.account import MAccount
from models.company import MCompany


class AccountResource(resources.MongoEngineResource):
        class Meta:
                serializer = CustomSerializer()
                queryset = MAccount.objects.all()
                allowed_methods = ('get', 'post', 'put','delete')
                resource_name = 'account'
                authorization= tastypie_authorization.Authorization()
```

Then if your urls.py file add this code:

```
v1_api = api.Api(api_name='v1')
v1_api.register(resources.AccountResource())
urlpatterns += patterns('', (r'^m/api/', include(v1_api.urls)))
```

Finally, you should be able to hit an API like

/m/api/v1/account/?format=json